# How can I prove the finite axiom of choice? (Actually, theorem)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\displaystyle \{X_i\}_{i\in I_m}$ a collection of nonempty sets, $I_m=\{i\in \mathbb N | 0<i\leq m\}$. Then show that there is a $x:I_m\rightarrow \displaystyle \bigcup_{i\in I_m} X_i$ such that $x(i)\in X_i$ (without axiom of choice).

I think I have to show that by induction.

For $n=1$,  I have to show that there is a $x:\{1\}\rightarrow \bigcup X_1$ such taht $x(1)\in X_1$.

Since $X_1$ is non-empty. Then it has at least one element. I will "select" one of them and call it $x$, this allows me to form the ordered pair $(1,x)$. So there is a function of $ x:\{1\}\rightarrow \bigcup X_1$ such that $x(1)\in X_1$, and the function $x$ is $(1,x)$.

Now, let's assume that it holds for $n$. That is, if $\{X_i\}_{i\in I_n}$ is any collection of non-empty sets, then there exists a function $x':I_n\rightarrow \bigcup _{i\in I_n} X_i $ such that $x'(i)\in X_i$

Let $A$ be a non-empty set which we will call $X_{n+1}$, this allows us to form a family of non-empty sets of $n+1$ elements $\{X_i\}_{i\in I_n+1 }$. Since $X_{n+1}$ is a non-empty, then it must have some element, say $y$, this allows us to form the ordered pair $(n+1,y)$ which if we join the set $x' $, we will obtain the following function $x^*:I_n\cup \{n+1\}\rightarrow \displaystyle \bigcup _{i\in I_n} X_i \cup X_{n+1}$ such that for all $i\in I_{n +1}$ it is true that $x^*(i)\in X_i$. Since $A$ was arbitrary, then we have found a required function for a collection of non-empty sets with $n+1$ elements.

This completes the proof, that is, that for all $n\in \mathbb N$ there exists a choice function for a finite collection of $n$ non-empty sets.

I am not sure if my attempted demonstration is correct, in any case it seems somewhat cumbersome to me, I would appreciate it if you could tell me if it is correct, and if so, how I could make it more understandable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution seems correct and very understandable, but maybe you find the approach below more amusing.

If you can accept that a function $\displaystyle x:I_m\to\bigcup_{i\in I_m} X_i$ is the same as an element $\displaystyle x\in\prod_{i\in I_m} X_i$, then all you have to do is to show that if $X_i\neq\varnothing~\forall i\in I_m$, then $\displaystyle\prod_{i\in I_m} X_i\neq\varnothing$, which can be done by induction!

**Base case:**
The claim is trivially true for $m=0$ and $m=1$. Also, given $A, B\neq\varnothing$, we have $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, so $(a, b)\in A\times B\neq\varnothing$ and the claim is true for $m=2$.

**Induction hypothesis:** Suppose the claim is true for $m$.

**Inductive step:**
Let $\{X_i\}_{i\in I_{m+1}}$ be a collection of non-empty sets. Then by our hypothesis $\displaystyle\prod_{i\in I_m} X_i\neq\varnothing$ and $X_{m+1}\neq\varnothing$, so, by our base case, $\displaystyle\prod_{i\in I_{m+1}} X_i=\left(\prod_{i\in I_m}X_i\right)\times X_{m+1}\neq\varnothing$, as we wanted.